# Change color of specific string

Tags: javascript, string, colors, replace

Does anyone know how I could change the color of a specific word if it is typed into a textarea? For instance, if the user types 'hello my friend', it would dynamically change 'hello' to green? Spent a large amount of time on google, and could not find anything very related. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`textarea`s aren't designed to be selectively colored.

Comment: is there a way to access the text and swap it through the DOM

Comment: No. It would be insanely complex.

Comment: see http://codemirror.net/ there is a textarea alternative which allow coloring - you can also extend it with a custom parser

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a textarea field because its only content can be text, not HTML.  You'll have to use an editable DIV or something, and then replace the word in string with `<span>word</span>` and apply a CSS class to the SPAN.

Answer (score 1):

In textarea you can't. But there is posibility of "editable div". See http://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML specs don't allow different fonts within the same textarea element.  You can't do this.

However, you can make an editor with JS that will do pretty much what you want.  These things tend to be pretty big projects, so you probably want something premade.  There is a list [here](http://www.htmlarea.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[image]