# JavaScript color strings when they appear

Tags: javascript, database, string, colors

I was wondering if there are any JavaScript functions that I could use to change the font color of certain strings in a text box.

Suppose I created a text box and every time the string hello appeared the font color would change to blue.

Are there any easy ways to make a database of strings so that this event would occur?

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Java, or JavaScript (for which "JS" is a common abbreviation)? They are not remotely the same thing.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657092/change-color-of-specific-string to see if it answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-trivial task, as text within a `textarea` can not be directly formatted. I would look into using a `div` or some other applicable tag, and use the [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute. This way the user can edit the text and you can control the formatting. At the simplest level you can listen for a key press and use regular expressions or the `replace` method to highlight all the words in your dictionary.

Here's a start, you'll need to flesh it out to perhaps be case-insensitive if that's what you want, and to keep track of the caret position which is a more complicated task:

http://jsfiddle.net/VJQHD/

You can look at a similar issue here: [Get caret (cursor) position in contentEditable area containing HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content/4770562#4770562)